HP Laserjet printer P1102w not working on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
My HP Laserjet printer P1102w stopped working after I installed Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS.
The job is sent to the printer, but after a few seconds its status is "stopped." I can't figure out how to get around this.

Does this answer your question?
